# How can I arbitarily rotate, rearrange etc pdf pages in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have an input.pdf which is "normal" (a number of pages all the same orientation and direction) and I want to create a new pdf which can arbitrarily rearrange the input pages

For example:

[image]

I only need rotation and scaling. Each input page will be present in its entirety as some component of the output. I don't need to fiddle with text, colours, cropping, etc.

In pseudocode these are all the features I need:

```
in = open_pdf("input.pdf")
out = new_pdf ()

p = createpage (size)
p.add (in.get_page(123), origin=(0,100), scale=(0.5,0.5), angle=degrees(270))
p.add (...)

out.add(p)

out.save("output.pdf")
```

Can I do this in Python?

If not Python, some other linux-friendly scripting language?

Comment: apparently, there is at least [one way](https://realpython.com/creating-modifying-pdf/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/), you can write a script to accomplish this task that looks very similar to your pseudocode.

Here’s some sample code, using [a nightly build of the Homotopy Type Theory textbook](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HoTT/book/03fe929f09f57c7bed6c9be862b8ef0e4486d48f/nightly/hott-online-1272-ga50f9bd.pdf) as input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

# matrix helper class

class AfMatrix:
    """ A matrix of a 2D affine transform. """

    __slots__ = ('__a', '__b', '__c', '__d', '__e', '__f')

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        self.__a = float(a)
        self.__b = float(b)
        self.__c = float(c)
        self.__d = float(d)
        self.__e = float(e)
        self.__f = float(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.__a
        yield self.__b
        yield self.__c
        yield self.__d
        yield self.__e
        yield self.__f

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return tuple(self) == tuple(other)

    @classmethod
    def compose(cls, *what):
        a, b, c, d, e, f = (
            1, 0,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
        )

        for rhs in what:
            A, B, C, D, E, F = rhs
            a, b, c, d, e, f = (
                a * A + b * C,
                a * B + b * D,
                c * A + d * C,
                c * B + d * D,
                e * A + f * C + E,
                e * B + f * D + F,
            )

        return cls(
            a, b,
            c, d,
            e, f
        )

    @classmethod
    def translate(cls, x=0, y=0):
        return cls(
            1, 0,
            0, 1,
            x, y
        )

    def __takes_origin(func):
        def translated_func(cls, *args, origin=(0, 0), **kwargs):
            if origin == (0, 0):
                return func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return cls.compose(
                cls.translate(-origin[0], -origin[1]),
                func(cls, *args, **kwargs),
                cls.translate(origin[0], origin[1])
            )
        return translated_func

    @classmethod
    @__takes_origin
    def shear(cls, x=1, y=1):
        return cls(
            x, 0,
            0, y,
            0, 0
        )

    @classmethod
    @__takes_origin
    def rotate(cls, angle):
        from math import cos, sin, radians

        angle = radians(angle)
        C = cos(angle)
        S = sin(angle)

        return cls(
             C,  S,
            -S,  C,
             0,  0
        )

#

reader = PdfFileReader('hott-online-1272-ga50f9bd.pdf')
writer = PdfFileWriter()

ipgs = [reader.getPage(i) for i in range(8)]

# page 1

writer.addPage(ipgs[0])

# page 2

opg1src = ipgs[2:5]

opg1 = writer.addBlankPage(0, 0)

yaccum = 0
for ipg in opg1src:
    opg1.mergeTransformedPage(ipg, AfMatrix.compose(
        AfMatrix.rotate(90),
        AfMatrix.translate(x=ipg.mediaBox.getHeight(), y=yaccum)
    ), expand=True)
    yaccum += ipg.mediaBox.getWidth()

# page 3

opg2 = writer.addBlankPage(
    ipgs[6].mediaBox.getWidth(),
    ipgs[6].mediaBox.getHeight()
)

opg2.mergeTransformedPage(ipgs[6], (
    AfMatrix.shear(x=1/3)
), expand=True)

opg2.mergeTransformedPage(ipgs[7], AfMatrix.compose(
    AfMatrix.translate(
        x=-opg2.mediaBox.getWidth() / 8,
        y=-opg2.mediaBox.getHeight() / 8
    ),
    AfMatrix.rotate(-15, origin=(opg2.mediaBox.getWidth(), 0)),
    AfMatrix.shear(x=0.75, y=0.75, origin=(opg2.mediaBox.getWidth(), 0))
), expand=False)

# output

with open('sample.pdf', 'wb') as ostream:
    writer.write(ostream)
```

And here’s the output:

[image: Pages of the HoTT textbook, transformed by the script. Page 1 contains the book cover, unmodified. Page 2 contains three front matter pages, rotated 90° counterclockwise, laid next to each other bottom to up. Page 3 contains the two first pages of the table of contents, sheared and tilted.]

Note on transformation matrices: in PDF and PostScript, the X coordinate grows rightwards and the Y coordinate grows upwards, like in mathematical custom (and unlike the custom in computer graphics, where Y grows downwards). *Unlike* mathematical custom, points are treated as row-vectors instead of column-vectors, and therefore appear on the left-hand side of matrix multiplication. This means matrix transformations compose left-to-right instead of right-to-left: the leftmost operation is applied first. Also, to make rotations by positive angles come out as counterclockwise (again like mathematical custom), the rotation matrix above appears transposed to its usual form.

When transforming pages, beware of content that falls off the page boundary on the original page; on the new page, it might actually render. (I have not found a solution to this yet.)

Comment: Thanks, this almost works https://pastebin.com/8gFMN44h the original pink/blue borders were tight to the edge of the page but now they appear with a margin https://imgur.com/a/nN5EheB is this a page attribute problem or did I screw up my matrices?

Comment: Test input/output for the above linked script [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/162gN5cz8jvE6Zz03KqqY7FmRDxsgxjp-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. If you look at the test-input.pdf in the tarball I shared above, it looks like the coloured borders are pretty tight to the page. If they're overflowing it's not by much, not by anything near to the big margins shown in the output. Something else is going on.

Comment: I cannot open the file, as I don't have a Google account. But you can observe the same phenomenon with the HoTT textbook: some of the sigma and pi symbols on the cover are normally rendered beyond the bounds of the page and start appearing when the contents are scaled.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d96bvnzjtqfr4w4/book-layout-test.tar?dl=0 please have a look at that

Comment: Ah, now I understood. You did not pass the origin point to the `scale` method (named `shear` in my sample). That, and the final transform is off by a quarter of the page height.

Comment: The origin is (0,0) by default so what difference does it make? And what do you mean "final transform is off by a quarter of the page height"? The y_offset is either 0 or height/2, where are you getting a quarter from? And if that's the explanation how come the x offset is also wrong? I want to accept this answer but I also want to get to the bottom of this. My current hack workaround is this: https://pastebin.com/mSiLYKv3

Comment: The shear transformation always has at least one fixed point, which is passed as the `origin` parameter. By default, `origin` is `(0, 0)`, which is the bottom left corner of the (output) page: setting it to the centre of the (output) page makes input pages positioned next to each other tightly.

Comment: An unrelated issue is that the starting value of `y_offset` is zero, which means (input) pages are positioned from the middle of the (output) page. Subtract quarter of the (output) page height to pack them from the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

```
    import PyPDF2

    pdf_in = open('original.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for pagenum in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(pagenum)
        if pagenum % 2:
            page.rotateClockwise(180)
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    pdf_out = open('rotated.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
    pdf_out.close()
    pdf_in.close()
```

[Source](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/05/01/rotating-pdf-pages-with-python/)

or

```
import fitz                            # <- PyMuPDF v 1.9.3
doc = fitz.open("mypdf.pdf")           # open the PDF
page = doc[n]                          # read page n (zero-based)
page.setRotate(-90)                    # rotate page by 90 degrees counter-clockwise
doc.save(doc.name, incremental = True)  # update the file - a sub-second matter
doc.close()
```

[source](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580713-rotate-a-pdf-page-in-3-lines/)

Answer (score 1):

mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page2, rotation, scale, tx, ty, expand=False)

rotation(degree): must be float

scale(between 0.0 and 1.0): must be float.

This is similar to mergePage, but the stream to be merged is translated,
rotated and scaled by appling a transformation matrix.
:param PageObject page2: the page to be merged into this one. Should be
an instance of :class:`PageObject<PageObject>`.
:param float tx: The translation on X axis
:param float ty: The translation on Y axis
:param float rotation: The angle of the rotation, in degrees
:param float scale: The scaling factor
:param bool expand: Whether the page should be expanded to fit the
dimensions of the page to be merged.

Input file:
[image: Inputfile]

Output file:
[image: Outputfile]

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter,pdf
from pathlib import Path

#  mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page2, rotation, scale, tx, ty, expand=False)

inpdf = PdfFileReader(open('input.pdf', 'rb'));
outpdf = PdfFileWriter();

# ----- page one   -----
page_1_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(0)
page_1_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.9,500,100,expand = False)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(1)
page_1_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.9,500,200,expand = False)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(2)
page_1_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.9,500,300,expand = False)

# ----- page Two   -----
page_2_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(3)
page_2_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 0.0 ,0.99,0,0,expand = False)

# ----- page Three   -----
page_3_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(4)
page_3_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 45.0 ,0.9,500,100,expand = False)


page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(5)
page_3_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 145.0 ,0.25,500,200,expand = False)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(6)
page_3_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 190.0 ,0.3,400,300,expand = False)
# ----- page Four   -----
page_4_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(7)
page_4_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 290.0 ,0.9,500,400,expand = False)
# ----- page Five   -----
page_5_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(8)
page_5_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.2,500,100,expand = False)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(9)
page_5_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.5,500,200,expand = False)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(10)
page_5_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 90.0 ,0.5,500,300,expand = False)
# ----- page Six   -----
page_6_in_output_file = outpdf.addBlankPage(1000,1000)

page_in_input_file = inpdf.getPage(11)
page_6_in_output_file.mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage(page_in_input_file, 180.0 ,0.9,500,100,expand = False)

with Path("output.pdf").open(mode="wb") as output_file:
    outpdf.write(output_file);
```