# Rotating and translating pdfs with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to write a little python function. The goal is to create booklets ready for printing from typeset pdfs. The function creates A4 spreads. It should take two defined pages from an A5 input pdf, rotate them and translate them so that they are next to each other as shown here:
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCQbW.png)

I almost got it to work:

```
import os
os.chdir('D:\\')

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PageObject

reader = PdfFileReader(open('My_A5_document.pdf','rb'))

# Size of an A4
new_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, 595, 841)

new_page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(reader.getPage(1), 90, 0, 0, False)
new_page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(reader.getPage(2), 90, 0, 0, False)

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.addPage(new_page)

with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

However, the [function](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PageObject.html#PyPDF2._page.PageObject.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage) `mergeRotatedTranslatedPage` is moving the body in ways I cannot understand and it takes it outside of the actual A4 page (with no translation, next to the page on the lower left side). I cannot understand if it first translates and then rotates, or the other way round. Also, which point does it rotate around? How can I get it to move properly? I.e, I am looking for the values a and b in `mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(~, 90, a, b)`.

Comment: @KJ but where is the origin and how is the coordinate system oriented?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834321/how-can-i-arbitarily-rotate-rearrange-etc-pdf-pages-in-python which solved my problem :)

Comment: see also https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/nicepdf/issues/4